# Multidimensional Fokker-Planck equation with exact solution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

In my research I consider the following diffusion processes obeying an Ito stochastic differential equation:
$$
d X_t = - \nabla \Psi(X_t) dt + \sqrt{2 \beta^{-1}} d W(t) \quad (1)
$$
Here $\Psi(x) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ - potential, $\beta$ is constant and $W(t)$ is standard n-dimensional Wiener process. Actually, the marginal densities $\rho_t$ of the process $X_t$ in form $(1)$ governed by Fokker-Planck equation:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho_t(x)}{\partial t} = \text{div}\left(\nabla \Psi(x) \rho_t\right) + \beta^{-1} \Delta \rho_t \quad (2)
$$
I have the following question: Is there a multidimensional nonlinear diffusion process which satisfies Fokker-Planck equation $(2)$ and has close-form solution. I know about Ornstein–Uhlenbeck processes (with quadratic potential) but they model linear diffusion. Thank you in advance for your ansvers! This will help me a lot.

Comment: Let's assume there exists some artificial potential for which you can solve explicitely (I doubt, there are). What would that be helpful for? What's your aim?

Comment: For $n =1$, with $\Psi (x) = x^3$, the process $X_t$ has closed form solution and of course its density satisfies $(2)$. Perhaps you could generalize this for the case $n \ge 2$

Comment: @Tobsn, thank you for your question. My aim is to test a new approach for solving such diffusion processes. Given a nonlinear process with exact solution I can recover how well my method works.